# NullPointerException error w/ declaring a graphics object

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, jframe

I can't seem to figure out why I get this error if I had already declared the Graphics a. How would I go about creating a new Graphics? ( Or is it an object and i'm just being stupid and trying to declare it as a variable?)

FYI:
I know that you can use the g Graphics but I want to make a local Graphics variable ( /or is it an object and i'm just being stupid).

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
public class World_Gen
{
    public World_Gen( int a, int b, String Name)
    {
    JFrame aFrame = new JFrame (Name);
    aFrame.setSize (a,b);
    aFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    aFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
import java.awt.Graphics.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class launcher
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    World_Gen Gen = new World_Gen (1000,2000,"My map");
    draw Box = new draw (10,10);
    Box.drawRect();
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class draw extends JFrame
{ 
 int XCords;
 int YCords;
 Graphics a; // Declared graphics a here.
 public draw (int Xcord, int Ycord)
    {    
    XCords = Xcord;
    YCords = Ycord;
    }

 public void drawRect ()
 {
     a.drawRect (XCords, YCords, 10,10); // This is where the run-time error pops up
 } 
}
```

Comment: Extra brownie points to whoever doesn't complain about all the imports (I use BlueJ as a compiler and it makes me put them in for all the classes)

Comment: `Graphics a;` makes `a=null;`. If you want something else to happen, go with `a = new ...`

Comment: @iluxa: well, you can't create Graphics objects via `a = new ...`, since it is an abstract class, and in fact I've never seen it created that way. Either you get it from the JVM via the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, or less likely the `paint(Graphics g)` method, or you get it from your BufferedImage via a call to `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()`. But again, "go with `a = new ...` just doesn't work in this situation and should not be recommended.

Comment: Just noticed you were given advice on how to do painting in your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19479305/131872) which you ignored. And you wonder why you are having problems again? We give advice for a reason. That reason is to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is null because you never assign a Graphics object to the variable. Anyway that code is completely wrong and should never be done like that.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel. Then you use the Graphics object that is passed to this method to do your painting.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples and more information.

Also, you would never extend JFrame like you do just to create a class with a couple of methods. Your class has nothing to do with a frame.

Learn an use standard Java naming conventions. Any tutorial or example in this forums will follow the standards. Class names should start with an upper case character.

You have lots of reading to do. I suggest you read the link I gave you and bookmark the Table of Contents because it contains all the basic information needed for creating a GUI.

Comment: @OladamOladam: He gives good advice and you call it "flaming"? And he **does** answer your question -- 1) you don't assign a valid Graphics object to your Graphics variable which is the reason for your NullPointerException (or NPE), and 2) Swing drawing shouldn't even be done by your current approach, that you'll be far better off, and won't have to deal with NPE if you draw the way recommended in the tutorials that he provided a link to. You know, you'll be much better off heeding his advice and growing a thicker skin.